# CouchDB Lucene response errors

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I am having a problem in accessing couchdb-lucene properly, and well the story goes like this:

Before the problem occurred, the old developer developed a project that is running perfectly on couchdb-lucene. As time goes by the couchdb required larger space, the client tried to upgrade the storage space for the database. Then client accidentally deleted parts of the project that includes the couch database file, ini configurations and the couchdb-lucene itself.

We have re-installed the couchdb-lucene, put up back the configuration files in the ini, restart couchdb. The real problem is when I am trying to make a query against it using curl, it returns either a 404 or 500 response, and now the application that I am trying to fix responds "Undefined index: reason" on html view.

**Some info that might be helpful**

Server: Debian GNU/Linux 7

Language: PHP

Framework: Laravel

CouchDB version: 1.6.1

CouchDB-Lucene version: 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT

**Local.ini**

```
[couchdb]
;max_document_size = 4294967296
uuid = add1dea463fa3e52a7d719fb99277610
os_process_timeout=60000

[httpd]
port = 5985
;bind_address = 127.0.0.1

[httpd_global_handlers]
_fti = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://127.0.0.1:5985">>}

[ssl]
ssl_certificate_max_depth = 1

[external]
fti= /usr/bin/python /root/couchdb-lucene/couchdb-lucene/couchdb-external-hook.py

[httpd_db_handlers]
_fti = {couch_httpd_external, handle_external_req, <<"fti">>}

[compaction_daemon]
min_file_size = 21474836480

[compaction]
_default = [{db_fragmentation, "70%"}, {view_fragmentation, "60%"}, {from, "23:00"}, {to, "04:00"}]
```

**curls and responses**

```
curl localhost:4807
- {"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"add1dea463fa3e52a7d719fb99277610","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation","version":"1.6.1"}}

curl localhost:5985
curl localhost:5985/dbname
curl localhost:5985/_fti
curl localhost:5985/_config
- 
{"couchdb-lucene":"Welcome","version":"1.0.2-SNAPSHOT"}

curl localhost:5984
curl localhost:5984/_config
- 
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

curl localhost:5985/insightout/_fti/_design/lucene/device_reading?q=couchDbId%3A%222708e7c7a5479895391f419c58b5def6%22+AND+sort_readon%3A%5B1441423093+TO+1441423993%5D
-
{"code":500}
```

Hope you guys could help me out, thanks!

Comment: I had a problem like that in my Cloudant DB (a copy of CouchDB for cloud) and I needed to re-create the indexes for my models to make it work again.